# How i can add many RecyclerView into a Activity?

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview

I try to list a RecyclerView into a Activity but it impossible

This is MainActivity

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout layoutMain = new LinearLayout(this);
    layoutMain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView(layoutMain);
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    RecyclerView recList = new RecyclerView(this);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    custom_button buttons = new custom_button(this, "button");
    Button buttons2 = new Button(this);
    buttons2.setText("button2");

    ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(createList(3));
    recList.setAdapter(ca);

    layoutMain.addView(buttons); // this is custom button

    layoutMain.addView(recList); // this is RecyclerView but it

    layoutMain.addView(buttons2); 

}
```

this is  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwtSu.png)  when it complete

And when i add many View into a activity it can't scroll :'(

Anyone help me solve this problem

Give me some keyword or any TUT , so many thank . . .

p/s : i just want make a layout like google store featured list like this
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS2bR.jpg)

Comment: Use a relative layout. Add button with param as alignParent top button 2 as alignParent bottom and recycler view with layout params above button 2 and below button. This will give you the desired layout.
Consider giving meaningful names to buttons, and also go through java naming convention(custom_button ? )

Comment: ` ALIGN_PARENT_TOP
  CENTER_IN_PARENT
  ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM
`

:'( not working can you help me fix this stupid code

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout as the root and set your RelativeLayout.LayoutParams on your button to align to bottom.
You can also achieve it with FrameLayout (margin & gravity) but as far as I can remember, it was not working well on Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable scrolling, use ScrollView as the `layoutMain`.
It has a LinearLayout in it as a default. So I recommend to make a layout xml to do it easily.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: @ĐặngXuânVui Yes, that's why I recommend to make a layout xml. Make it, and set an ID for the child LinearLayout, and you can access this LinearLayout in onCreate() by findViewById(id). Then same with the code above.

Comment: Thank so much , but i don't think it work ( because i did try )
. . . and layout above is stupid . . . . i think you can suggest for me a better way to make a layout like google store . . . . . .thanks

Comment: @ĐặngXuânVui You can get hints from this page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html . Recommended widgets are ScrollView, LinearLayout(horizontal, vertical), ListView.